# Вводное слово и запятая.

Tags: пунктуация

**Когда же наконец будут известны результаты, абитуриенты, точнее уже студенты смогут немного расслабиться и хоть немного отдохнуть перед началом нового этапа в их жизни.**
Нужна ли запятая после "точнее"? Это вводное слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вводное слово стоит в начале обособленного оборота, то запятая ставится только перед вводным словом. Поэтому надо добавить запятую после "студенты".

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Запятыми выделяется **точнее уже студенты**. Это уточнение.

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая нужна. Здесь слово "точнее" имеет значение вводного ("точнее говоря"). См. правило "Уточняющие члены предложения", например, здесь: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/46.htm

А после слова студенты запятая НЕ ставится, т. к. согласно правилу слово "точнее" уже обособлено (запятыми).

Эх, грамотеи!

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя слова "точнее, вернее, скорее" имели особый статус и всегда выделялись запятыми сами по себе, а не вместе с обособленным оборотом: Абитуриенты, точнее, уже студенты смогут немного расслабиться. Согласно современным нормам эти вводные слова подчиняются общим правилам и не отделяются от обособленного оборота: Абитуриенты, точнее уже студенты, смогут немного расслабиться.